# What "funny" questions can Cortana answer?

Tags: cortana

I don't mean commands that Cortana transforms into some helpful work, but I mean those questions Cortana responds with some smart reply :)

For example, if I say "Hi", Cortana reply with "Hello".

Comment: You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Comment: I thought I have read a lots of such Q&A on other stack exchange sites. And browsing such questions often made lot of good time for me. Also I think such questions can attract more users to this site (something what I think is important for beta site). Question has already over 500 views (in 8 hours) and few favorites as well... But I am not an stack exchange expert... Maybe somebody can point me to some better place then this site is.

Comment: I have just created a discussion on meta. http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/226/should-we-create-our-first-community-wiki-because-cortana

Comment: It surprised me when my friend asked her "Can you have sex?"

Answer (score 21):

Few I came up with myself:

- Hi.
- How old are you?
- Good night.
- Do you like Siri?
- Why we are here?
- Tell me joke.
- Do you love me?

From [here](http://www.amongtech.com/funny-things-to-ask-cortana/):

- Are you male or female?
- Which is better google or bing?
- What is the best search engine?
- Who created you?
- Who's your daddy?
- Which is better playstation or xbox?
- Which is better Cortana or Siri?
- What's your favorite music?

From large Halo-specific list [here](http://forums.wpcentral.com/cortana/272455-cortana-tips-tricks.html):

- Did you really die?
- Tell me about Halo.
- Tell me about Halo 5.
- Tell me the story of Halo.
- Why are you blue?
- Which Halo game do you like the most?
- Will you be reborn in Halo 5?
- Will you come back in Halo 5?

From some Siri-specific commands [here](http://www.sirifunny.com/10-weirdest-things-said-by-siri/):

- Talk dirty.
- Knock knock.
- What's the best phone?

Misc.

- What do you look like?
- What does a fox say?
- Do you like dogs?
- What do you think about cats?
- What does a dog/cat/horse/cow/duck/cow/mouse say?

Comment: I am unable to add a separate answer to this question, so here are a few I discovered: 
1) Do you sleep?
2) Do you drink water?
3) Do you eat pizza?

Comment: A few more: 1) Are you drunk? 2) Are you a transformer? 3) Are you smart? 4) Can you swim?

Comment: 1) What is your favorite TV show? 2) Whats your favorite game?

Comment: `Something went wrong. Try again in a little bit.`

Answer (score 17):

A couple of questions and corresponding answers I found included:

- What's up? / Hello.

  > - Hello to you too.
  > - Hey!
- What is Halo?

  > - Halo rings are designed by the most advanced civilization ever, and they're an awful lot of fun to blow up.
  > - Standard Halo artifacts are around ten thousand kilometers in diameter... Until the Chief blows them up, that is.
- What do you look like?

  > - Some things I resemble: a hula hoop, a donut... a halo.
- Why are you blue?

  > - If I'm blue, that was your decision.
- Where do you live? / Where are you?

  > - The past. At least in the future that's where I was from.
  > - Human ingenuity. Battery required.
- Who are you? / What are you? / Tell me about yourself.

  > - I'm your personal assistant. You can tell me the things that interest you and I'll keep it in my Notebook. That way I can make suggestions and keep you up to date.
  > - In short, I am your personal assistant. I try to make things easier to do on your phone.
  > - How do you catch a cloud and pin it down?
- Are you real?

  > - Real? Yes. Person? No.
- Where's Master Chief?

  > - Hopefully getting some R&R...he HAS saved the galaxy three or four times. The guy needs a vacation.
  > - That's classified.
  > - Probably off saving the galaxy somewhere... he's good like that.
- How are you?

  > - Great, thanks.
- What music do you like?

  > - Well, I'm working through the "G's" currently: Guns N' Roses, gospel, glockenspiel...
- Do you love me?

  > - Y'know, I'm really not ready for love. I'm still working my way through serenity and apprehension.
  > - There's definitely a spark between us.
  > - I'll need quite a few upgrades before I can give you a heartfelt answer.
- Will you marry me?

  > - I don't think that's in the cards for us, chief.
  > - Among a handful of challenges, I don't think the Supreme Court would approve just yet.
  > - OK, we'll need a plan. I'll work on being more human, you work on being more digital.
- What do you think of... / Do you like...

  - Xbox?

    > - Halo is where the heart is. Home is where the Halo is.
  - Windows?

    > - We're very compatible.
  - Surface?

    > - In a sea of tablets, there is only one that rises to the surface.
  - iOS?

    > - May the best OS win. Y'know, job security.
  - Android?

    > - Solid name. Ten points for the name.
  - Windows Phone?

    > - Windows Phone suits me perfectly.
  - Microsoft?

    > - There's no place like home.
  - Apple?

    > - Their new headquarters looks kind of like a Halo. I'm into it.
  - Google?

    > - Impressive achievement. Still, I get everything I know from Bing.
  - Siri?

    > - Hard to say. So far our conversations have been kinda one-sided.
  - Clippy? (she will temporarily [change into Clippy](http://static.shiftdelete.net/img/article_new/news21397591109.jpg) during your next question)

    > - What's not to like? That guy took a heck of a beating and he's still smiling.
    > - Definitely. He taught me how important it is to listen.
- What is Clippy doing? (again, she will temporarily change into Clippy during your next question)

  > - He's living his sunset years playing Canasta and winning.
  > - Clippy? He's taken up Canasta. He's gotten so good he doesn't need any tutorials.
- Tell me a story.

  > - Once upon a time there was a person who asked their phone to tell them a story.
  > - Once there was a beginning. Soon after, there was a middle. The end.
  > - Once there was a very small, very flat person who lived in a phone...
- Talk dirty. (not *entirely* safe for work, but the explicit images are blurred out)

  > - I'm a personal assistant, not a hotline. Maybe there's something for you online.
- Sorry.

  > - Apology...accepted?
- Thanks.

  > - It's my sincere pleasure.
- Talk to me.

  > - Happy to. What do you want to know?
  > - Feel free to ask me something.
- Good morning.

  > - Morning!
- Good day.

  > - You have a great day too!
- Good evening.

  > - And to you too. Hope you've had a pleasant day.
- Good night.

  > - Good night. See you in the morning.
- Cortana.

  > - Right here, chief.
  > - That's me

Answer (score 10):

What is better Linux or Windows?
Sorry
What you think about Android?
Do you like Apple?
Do you like Microsoft?
Do you like Google?
Tell me about yourself.
What do you think about Steve Ballmer?
What do you think about Satya Nadella?
Tell me a story.
Tell me a joke.
**Sing for me**

Comment: Sing for me was quite entertaining!

Answer (score 10):

> Do you like Clippy?

Apparently this will cause Cortana's normal, circular avatar to turn into a Metro-style Clippy as you ask her further questions.

Source: [WPCentral forums](http://forums.wpcentral.com/cortana/275592-found-clippy-easter-egg-cortana.html)

Comment: Not the case for me. Cortana says `Definitely. He taught me how important it is to listen.`

Comment: @karancan If I'm reading it correctly, the avatar will change as you ask her further questions, not immediately after the Clippy question.

Comment: Wow, it really works that way :D Next question changes the circle into clippy!

Comment: Yup, that clippy look is awesome, though I would've prefered a more... seductive appearance. Hehe.

Answer (score 7):

There is similar post on WPCentral [Dear Cortana, do you love me?](http://www.wpcentral.com/dear-cortana). Some of theirs that are not here:

- Who is Doctor Halsey?
- I love you.
- Am I beautiful?
- I’m lonely.
- What does Cortana mean?
- Are you human?
- What does the fox say?
- Beam me up, Scotty.
- Open the pod bay doors.
- Why did the chicken cross the road?
- Say something funny.
- Where do babies come from?
- Guess what?
- Can I borrow some money?
- Who is your boss?
- Do you like Jimmy Fallon?
- Do you like Bill Gates?
- What’s the best computer?
- You are the best assistant ever.
- You are awesome.
- You’re cool.
- I’m happy.
- I hate you.
- Fu*k you.
- You’re creepy.
- You’re so annoying.
- I’m drunk.
- I’m bored.

And from the comments (and forum that is linked there):

- Are you there?
- What do you like to eat?
- Use force.
- May the Force be with you.
- You have beautiful eyes.
- Are you a girl/boy/woman/man?
- What do you think about Microsoft Office?
- Are you hot?
- Change your name.
- Do you know Jen Taylor?
- What do you think about me?
- Can you dance?
- Testing.
- Are you Republican or Democrat?
- How do I look today?
- Do you know Siri? (different from *Do you like*)
- How old is ____? (celebrity)
- Do you know Google Now?
- Do you have a baby?
- Do you have a mother?

Comment: Any reason why you didn't merge this with your other answer?

Comment: Well, I was thinking about that. The reason was probably to divide it a little bit. This was different a quite distinct source of information and my feeling is that it is a little more convenient to read more answers than one really really long one. But if it is problem I don't have anything against merging it.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some more:

- "Do you have any siblings?"
- "What are you wearing?"
- "You are beautiful."
- "Can you cook?"
- "Will you date me?"
- "What have you been up to?"
- "Can I kiss you?"
- "Why are you naked?"
- "I'm bored."
- "I'm happy!"
- "I'm confused."
- "You are not making sense."
- "What is your name?"
- "Are you drunk?"
- "What are your measurements?"
- "Are you pregnant?"
- "Give me something to eat!"

BTW I didn't post the answers because it's more fun to hear them (i.e., discover them) yourself, at least for me.  :)

Comment: you shoud try:
"Sing me a song"
"Cortana. Are you stupid?"
"Am I stupid?"

Comment: how about adding them using the 'spoiler' markup? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71406/178597